# Register FilterRegistrationBean of same type twice

Tags: filter, spring-boot, javabeans

**How to register a filter bean of same type on second time in spring boot FilterRegistrationBean?**

I have a scenario, where I need to register a same type of filter bean twice for different url patterns. Say *IAMFilterBean1* of type *IAMFilterBean* was built with one auth key for internal user identifications. And *IAMFilterBean2* of same type *IAMFilterBean* was built with different auth key for external user identifications. Now I need to register both these IAMFilterBean1 and IAMFilterBean2 with spring boot FilterRegistrationBean for filtering different url patterns!

I tried like below,

```
@Bean
public Filter iamFilterBean1() {
    return new IamFilterBean("auth_key_1");
}

@Bean
public Filter iamFilterBean2() {
    return new IamFilterBean("auth_key_2");
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(iamFilterBean1());
    registration.setName("iamFilterBean1");

    List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
    urlPatterns.add("/api/internal/auth");
    registration.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(iamFilterBean2());
    registration.setName("iamFilterBean2");

    List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
    urlPatterns.add("/api/external/auth");
    registration.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
    return registration;
}
```

But it doesn't work for me! it filters all my requests not only the defined ones? Can you please help me on resolving this.

Comment: The code you posted won't work... As you have 2 beans named `filterRegistration` one will override the other. Post actual code, not made up code. Next to that you might want to remove the `@Bean` from the filter as that will register a `Filter` in the context, which are also detected which might lead to registration twice.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions @M.Deinum After naming the filter beans everything working as expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To register two filters of one type you will need to name them (or name at least one):

```
@Bean(name="filterRegistrationBean2")
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(iamFilterBean2());
    registration.setName("iamFilterBean2");

    List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
    urlPatterns.add("/api/external/auth");
    registration.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: Somehow the name attributes in Bean annotation doesn't works for me. But I have renamed the bean itself as "filterRegistrationBean1" and its works! thanks.

Comment: This worked for me. What it did not work is to have 2 different bean names for the filter beans themselves.